# Is it possible to manage non-gui nodes with a separate node with GUI?

Tags: server, gui, remote-access

Quick question: I have several Ubuntu non-gui instances running.  My question is: Is it possible to setup a "Management Machine" with the the Ubuntu GUI - like you can do for Windows?  I would like to view the non-GUI Ubuntu machines' files from the GUI of the Ubuntu management machine, hopefully in the default explorer. If that is possible I assume I would also be able to install 3rd party data tools to the Ubuntu GUI to manage data sets on the non-GUI nodes as well, I.E. MySQL. I'm a Windows Admin but I just inherited a small Linux segment so this is all new to me.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what this means.  What should this "Management Machine" do?  If you just want to monitor the nodes, use something like Icinga ( https://www.icinga.org/ ), but that's a web interface you can just access from your desktop.   I'd ask you to explain what, in your mind, this "Management Machine" should do.   For management, we use `ssh` and for configuration, tools like `puppet`, `ansible`or `cfengine`.

Comment: I'll get back to you about this when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for the clarification.  I will first tackle the "accessing files" part.  Personally, I'd just script the nodes in such a way that the processed data would be pushed to a central fileserver instead, but... that's not your question.  You could install Samba on each of the nodes and use typical Windows shares, but there is an easier way.  I assume that, by now, you are familiar with `ssh` to connect to your nodes to access their command line?  Well, this service encompasses a whole file server service.

Open the Ubuntu file manager (Cabinet logo in the "Dock").  You will notice ( on the bottom left hand side something called "Connect to Server".  It is highlighted in the screenshot below.  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, it might look slightly different on older version.  If you don't find it, I can look it up on 14.04.

[image: Screenshot Nautilus with Connect to Server]

Now double click that and you'll get the following interface.  The interface in Ubuntu 12.04 was so much better because it guided you.  Now you need to know exactly what to type.  It's idiotic, but still.  If you know what to type, it's easy.  Big "if" obviously.
[image: Connect to server interface]

So what do you type.  Basically, a URL to a resource on the network.  To use a Windows Share (Samba in Linux nomenclature), you'd type `smb://nameofthesever/nameoftheshare`, so apart from the slashes instead of the backslashes and `smb:` in front, the same as on Windows.  However, your nodes do not have Samba, so we are going to use ssh.  That looks slightly different: `ssh://username@nameofnode/full/path/to/desired/folder`.  Type what fits for you.  You can also use IP addresses instead of the name of the node, I am obviously unfamiliar with your infrastructure.

Press connect and it will ask you for the password of the user.  When everything is successful, you end up with a dialog asking for a password, where you will fill in the password of the user you used in the connection string.  You should now be seeing the files of that nodes in your graphical interface.  You will notice your connection in the left and list with a "eject" button next to it.  If you right click on that text, you can add a bookmark so you don't have to do the procedure all over again next time.  This might seem cumbersome if you have thousands of nodes, I'm well aware of that.  It's basically the equivalent of `net use` graphically.  If you want to make logging in using `ssh` easier you can use [keyfiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) for that, because it allows basically passwordless login from one station to another.  That is a rather huge topic, but worth it once you get more the hang of Linux.

Now let's tackle your MySQL question.  It is hard to generalize, because it does depend a lot on your configuration.  In a default installation, MySQL will only listen to localhost, so you wouldn't be able to access it from network.  You have to explicitly allow that on the server.  Furthermore, you need connection data to access the database.  Usernames in MySQL aren't simple usernames, they are always comprised of a host part and as such you won't simply have a user called `chris` with a password, but you have something like `christ@workstation007` and a password, meaning you can only remotely connect from `workstation007 with a user named`chris`.  Frankly, it's a full blown clusterfuck and very confusing at first.  I will make my work easy here and assume you have all that set up right.  In that case, it comes down to suggesting software you can use to connect to your MySQL instances.  I'm going to recommend two, but they have fully different use cases.

1. phpmyadmin - It basically is a web interface to MySQL databases with really pretty much anything you can think of.  Ok, perhaps database design isn't it.  Since it's web-based, you usually have a server which has it installed and that server connects to your different MySQL instances.  It's great for teams, since no-one actually needs to install any software locally on their desktops.
2. MySQL Workbench - I don't really have experience with this, but it is the official graphical interface for MySQL.  Since it's a native program, it might be more to what you are used to.

I understand many things will still be unclear, that's normal.  Happened to all of us.  Linux isn't hard, Ubuntu even less so.  It's just a different mindset.  For example, I still don't get why you can't manage your cluster directly from your desktop over the network.  Unless the cluster is on a totally cut of network segment, I don't see the need.  But, I don't know enough about the infrastructure and your needs, so basically, I'm just guessing.

Hope this helped somehow.  Learn Linux, it's worth it!  (With the direction Microsoft is taking, you might want to keep an escape path open. ;-) )

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.  Much better answer than I was expecting.  I will proceed with your input and if I run into any snags I'll try to google my way out of it before posting again.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you need any additional information and I can provide, just ask.